# In how many different ways can these fruits be eaten in succession considering only the type of fruit?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A basket contains 3 mangoes, 2 papayas and 2 kiwis. In how many different ways can these fruits be eaten in succession considering only the type of fruit?

For me the answer is $3! C^7_3C^4_2C^2_2 = 1260$, but the answer seems $7\times6 \times 5=210$.

Can you explain to me where have I done the error?

Comment: Assume that you can't tell one mango from another; likewise papayas and kiwis. ("considering only the **type** of fruit")

Comment: Since we only care about the type of fruit, choosing the positions of the mangoes, papayas, and kiwis within the sequence completely determines the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we are "considering only the **type** of fruit".

The answer here is basically the number of arrangements of **MMMPPKK**. This is a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_unique_permutations_of_words),
$$\binom{7}{3,2,2} = \frac{7!}{3!\;2!\;2!} = \frac{7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{2\cdot 2} = 7\cdot 6\cdot 5$$